# xcode 4.2 - Problems upgrading app to iOS 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, configuration, distribution, xcode4.2

I have a few apps on the app store that I haven't touched in a year and a half. The inevitable happened and one of them finally broke with the iOS 5 upgrade. I've downloaded xcode 4.2 and have been trying to get my head around iOS dev again.

After fixing the bugs and getting rid of all the deprecation warnings I'm struggling with distribution. I'm trying to get an ad hoc distribution working right now so I can convince myself I'll be doing the right thing when I do the final app store distribtion.

The key things I have set are:

*Target*
* Deployment Target: 5.0
* Devices: iPhone
* Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 5.0)
* Build Active Architecture: Distribution=Yes (No for others)
* Code Signing Identity: Distibution set to the ad hoc profile I'd like to build for (although I'm still getting a *Provisioning profile is expiring* warning on the project)
* iOS Deployment Target: iOS 5.0

*Project*
* Configurations. This is an issue. I found a video which showed how to select a configuration but all of mine say "No Configuration Set". When I click the dropdown there are no options and the very helpful link to help files asks for a login and then throws an error when I try to type in it.

These are probably quite straightforward issues but I'm struggling to find the answers. When I was working in 2010 I was able to use a document called *iPhone Developer Program User Guide* but I can't seem to find an equivalent for the latest xcode configuration. I was hoping to avoid having to go back to school on all this stuff but if that is what is required then I'm happy to hear it.

Thanks in advance,

Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is embarrassing, I had failed to recognise that the Active Configuration setting had moved from the menu to the chevroned button at the top left of the page (I was still building for the simulator).

After realising that I then had to figure out where Xcode 4 was now building to (Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> Derived Data -> Click arrow to get to folder).

Now to work out why the ad hoc distribution builds but refuses to install on my iPhone. Perhaps has something to do with the persistent "Provisioning profile is expiring" warning which I can't shake despite checking, double-checking and triple-checking that I am indeed using the new profile I just created (I've cleaned the build and even checked the project.pbxproj file). I think this deserves a separate post though (after doing a bit more searching for a similar issue).

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got the configuration set to "distribution" in the target, then the project should follow along.  If you're over 12 months behind, then your provisionings have probably expired.  You should go through the directions on the developer.apple.com site precisely, and that will probably solve your problems.